# using data in dynamodb

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am querying a dynamodb table and i am getting the results required, however i cant seem to figure out how to pass the results for use.

I haven't included the params array but its standard.  This code lives inside of a lambda.

What im trying to achieve is to make this update the "value" parameter with the contents of "item[0]['the_data'];

```
var value = "not changed after the dbase query, why?";

    dynamodb.query(queryparams, function(err, data) {
       if (err) {
          console.log("Query Error", err);
       } else {
           if(data.Count > 0){
              var item = data.Items;
              value = item[0]['the_data'];
              //console.log("The data: " + JSON.stringify(item));
           }

       }
     });
```

Comment: Are you using `value` inside or outside your callback? Can you show us by putting a `console.log(value)` where you are using it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

It’s shows in CloudWatch, and the log when I use the test functionality in the lambda itself.

The only way around it so far has been to create an s3 object, and creating another gateway and function to return that objects content.